# Is it bad to use a struct and treat it like a class to solve the dependency in Golang?

Tags: oop, go, struct, dependency-injection, dependencies

I wrote a lot PHP with the OOP frameworks before, and I'm learning Golang,

When I was using PHP, The `class` is useful that I could pass a `$model` in to my class then **share it between functions**:

```
class User {
   function __construct(UserModel $model) {
       $this->model = $model
   }

   function delete($id) {
       $this->model->delete($id);
   }

   function update($id) {
       $this->model->update($id);
   }
}

$UserModel = new UserModel();
$User      = new User($UserModel);
$User->delete(1);
```

But there's no `class` in Golang, I knew that I could treat structs like a class:

```
type User struct {
    model *models.User
}

func (u *User) Delete(id int) {
    u.model.Delete(id)
}

func (u *User) Update(id int) {
    u.model.Update(id)
}

userModel := &models.User{}
user      := User{model: userModel}
user.Delete(1)
```

I felt like the `struct` is **used to store the information**, and **the method of the struct should be used to modify the value of the struct**.

But right now I made a struct just because I want to **treat it like a class** and **solve the dependency** problem, is it bad to use such approach in Golang?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing (other than passing `int` to those functions instead of `id` – it won't compile as-is).

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction, like I said, I'm from a OOP background, but I'm not sure if I should bring my "old thoughts" to the new language, because I heard a lot about "Don't use OOP in Golang", that's why I'm not sure if I was doing it right or wrong.

Comment: I think admonitions against using OOP in Go are silly. Clearly, Go is not a typical object-oriented language in the model of C++ or Java, but it certainly has features that allow you to use OO principles in developing software. As you said, Go doesn't have traditional classes, but it has structs, interfaces, methods with receivers, and embedding, all of which allow you to do things that are similar to what you can do in an OO language. Some notable exceptions are the absence of constructors and destructors and there being no direct equivalent of subclassing (although embedding is similar).

Comment: im also unclear what you're asking so some random thougths: dependency injection is the way to go; you can certainly think of a struct definition as a class and instances of that struct as objects; and you may want a `func NewUser(m *models.User) User { ... }`

Comment: @Plato I considered to use `func NewUser(m *models.User) User { ... }` before, but I had to pass the `models.User` around my functions, plus, it's not flexible if I want to add a new parameter for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From overall conceptual standpoint there is nothing wrong in your implementation.

On a detailed view there are inconsistencies that raise questions.

In all cases below there is a potential concurrency issue due to data shared across various Delete calls.

### Case A

If models.User{} does all the work, then why can't we just

```
userModel := &models.User{}
userModel.Delete(userId)
```

## Case B

If User is our public interface:

```
user      := User{model: userModel}
user.Delete(1)
```

then taking userId to delete is redundant and shall be done as:

```
user.Delete()
```

userId is taken from user context.

## Case C

Otherwise, we might want to make userModel to be set for all User instances:

```
package User;
// private package level variable
var model = userModel
func Delete(userId int) {
    model.Delete(userId)
}
...
User.Delete(userId)
```

## Conclusion

Each case above solves the same problem with a slightly different emphasis.  Case A is straightforward.  Case B and C rely on underlying shared code that could be used with event notifications.  Case B and C are different in User scope.  In Case B User is a structure.  In Case C user is a package name.  I think Case C is used less often than Case B.  So, if use insist on having an underlying model, then Case B is probably the most intuitive solution from user code point of view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use interface with method
 In service (connect db)

```
// UserServiceInterface include method list
type UserServiceInterface interface {
    GetAll(helpers.ParamsGetAll) (models.PublicUsers, error)
    Get(int64) (models.User, error)
    Delete(int64) (bool, error)
    Create(models.User) (int64, error)
    Update(models.User) (models.User, error)
    CheckExistUsername(string) (bool, error)
    CheckExistEmail(string) (bool, error)
    CreateEmailActive(string, string, int64) error
    CheckExistUser(int64) (bool, error)
}

// UserService struct
type userService struct{}

// NewUserService to constructor
func NewUserService() userService {
    return userService{}
}

func (userService )GetAll (p helpers.ParamGetAll)(models.PublicUser, error) {
    code here....
}
```

In user controller

```
// UserController controller
type UserController struct {
    Service services.UserServiceInterface
}
    func (controller UserController) GetAll(c *gin.Context) {
    users, errGetAll := controller.Service.GetAll(params)
}
```